# Random Numbers in Python with Paramaters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Generate Random numbers with parameters.

So like random numbers from 1 to 10 and 15 to 20

The output would be either 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,15,16,17,18,19

The numbers from 10 to 15 would be excluded

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: You are vague as far as to just what the parameters are supposed to be. Are there always 4 parameters a,b,c,d with a < b < c < d. Something else? What is the probability distribution on the resulting numbers? Presumably uniform -- though you never specified. Unless clarified I would vote to close this question as being unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply construct a list of your choices using `range`, then pass it to `random.choice`:

```
import random

choices = [*range(1, 10), *range(15, 20)]
num = random.choice(choices)
```

Fortunately, this solution is also short enough to be condensed into 1 line:

```
num = random.choice([*range(1, 10), *range(15, 20)])
```

---

Someone pointed out (then deleted their comment) about excessive memory use with this solution and much larger numbers. If the range is drastically expanded, this solution can be used without actually creating a list of all possible choices:

```
import random

min1 = 1
max1 = 10

min2 = 15
max2 = 20

num_choices = (max1 - min1) + (max2 - min2)
n = int(random.random() * num_choices) + 1

if n >= max1 and n < min2:
    n += min2 - max1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list of numbers would be excluded and a range to generate the numbers. Like:

```
excluded = [10,11,12,13,14]
for i in range(1, 20):
    if i not in excluded:
        print(i)
```